# Check ACH credit transfer for customer in stripe using java

Tags: stripe-payments, stripes

Is there any way to check whether ACH credit transfer added to customer or not in stripe using java with using only customerid.

Answer (score 0):

ACH Credit Transfer is still only available on Stripe's legacy API called the [Source API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources/object) as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/ach-credit-transfer). Since it is not yet compatible with the PaymentMethod API you have to use one of the old calls in Java called `getSources()` which can be a bit hard to discover.

Your code would look something like this:

```
// Retrieve the customer with its legacy payment sources included
CustomerRetrieveParams retrieveParams =
  CustomerRetrieveParams.builder()
    .addExpand("sources")
    .build();

Customer customer = Customer.retrieve("cus_1234", retrieveParams, null);

// Filter payment sources down to just Sources
PaymentSourceCollectionListParams sourcesParams =
  PaymentSourceCollectionListParams.builder()
    .setObject("source")
    .build();

PaymentSourceCollection sources = customer.getSources().list(sourcesParams);

// Iterate over the Sources to find what you need
Iterable<PaymentSource> itSources =  sources.autoPagingIterable();
for (PaymentSource paymentSource : itSources) {
  Source source = (Source) paymentSource;
  System.out.println(source.getId());
  System.out.println(source.getType());
}
System.out.println("done");
```